# The package com.sun is not accessible. Java in Eclipse. Classic Problem, but nothing works for me

Tags: java, eclipse, package, com.sun.net.httpserver

Im trying to use the HttpServer Class from com.sun package but i can't import it. It keeps saying: "The package com.sun is not accessible."

I've tried every solution i could find in other questions about this topic. I've added a rule to have access to it to my libraries. I changed my JDK to another installed JDK17. I don't know what to do anymore. It's for my college homework, so it would be cool to get it running.

Does someone have a clue?

my code problem:
[image: my code problem]

the access rule:
[image: the access rule]

my current used jdk:
[image: my current used jdk]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `module-info.java` so you are using Java modules. Consequently you need to say that you are using the `jdk.httpserver` module which contains `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`.

You do that by adding the line:

```
  requires jdk.httpserver;
```

to your module-info.java. So something like:

```
module modulename
{
  requires jdk.httpserver;
}
```

where `modulename` is the name of your module.

Alternatively delete the `module-info.java` file to stop using the module system.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. i tried both ways and unfortunately adding the line to my module-info.java doesnt do anything and deleting it resulting in "The import com.sun.httpserver cannot be resolved." Does that mean i don't have the necessary .jar-file with the wanted class? i tried download it and added it to my libraries for that java project but its still giving the error message.

Comment: Both ways work for me testing here. `jdk.httpserver` should be part of the standard JDK without needing downloads. I'm not sure what the problem is.